# Python way of changing the film gate

Tags: python, maya

What is the command for changing the film gate?

However, in my case, there are 2 film gates with the same values in terms of its camera aperture etc. but they are of different names, eg. 35 mm default and 35 mm delivery.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

comment was to long so heres another answer

if you look in that file at the bottom you can see

```
AEcameraFilmbackNew
```

thats where it populates the optionMenu

```
string $filmbackTable[] = globalFilmbackTable();
```

whish is at the top of that mel script

whish is a list of

```
            //  Name                                        Horiz    Vert     Squeeze
    (uiRes("m_AEcameraFilmbackNew.kTheatrical")),          "0.404", "0.295", "1.0",
    (uiRes("m_AEcameraFilmbackNew.kSuper")),                    "0.493", "0.292", "1.0",
    (uiRes("m_AEcameraFilmbackNew.kAcademy")),                "0.864", "0.630", "1.0",
    (uiRes("m_AEcameraFilmbackNew.kProjectionTV")),     "0.816", "0.612", "1.0",
    (uiRes("m_AEcameraFilmbackNew.kAperture")),         "0.980", "0.735", "1.0",
    (uiRes("m_AEcameraFilmbackNew.kProjection185")),  "0.825", "0.446", "1.0",
    (uiRes("m_AEcameraFilmbackNew.kAnamorphic")),          "0.864", "0.732", "2.0",
    (uiRes("m_AEcameraFilmbackNew.kProjection70")),        "2.066", "0.906", "1.0",
    (uiRes("m_AEcameraFilmbackNew.kVista")),                   "1.485", "0.991", "1.0",
    (uiRes("m_AEcameraFilmbackNew.kImax")),                           "2.772", "2.072", "1.0"
```

theres no simple way to set the preset, theyre are just saved settings that are populated with a script

Comment: So I can assume, using coding to change the presets in this case the film back will be impossible too?

Comment: Just means you need to take the Mel and re write it to do the same thing in python

Answer (score 0):

not everything is an attribute in the AE (attribute editor)
 its a dynamically built part of the ui to allow for custom settings to be made

the film gate is not an attribute just an enum of settings somehwere else

select your camera and run this, 
you wont see film gate listed

```
for i in sorted(pm.ls(sl=True)[0].listAttr()):
    print i
```

when you change it by hand you get the following

```
AEwhichCameraFilmback perspShape2.horizontalFilmAperture  perspShape2.verticalFilmAperture perspShape2.lensSqueezeRatio;
AEcameraFilmbackModified "perspShape2";
AEcameraFilmbackModified "perspShape2";
AEadjustFOV perspShape2.focalLength perspShape2.horizontalFilmAperture;
```

which is all mel so this leaves you to believe its some command

in mel(and only mel) there is a whatIs command

```
whatIs AEadjustFOV ;
//Result: Mel procedure found in: C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2014/scripts/AETemplates/AEcameraTemplateCommon.mel
```

which again proves its custom for the AE and not a direct attribute

if you ruin whatIs on all those commands they will probably lead back to the same mel file

also i find the quickest way to get to these files is paste the path in a web browser and it will pop right open

you could most likely find where its building that option menu and find the command it runs on change

Comment: Okay.. This is tough. Actually I did chanced upon the `AEcameraFilmbackNew.mel` script but could hardly make a sense of it. Not to mention that mine seems to be a tricky situation in which I have 2 similar film back naming, both in which contains the same values..

Answer (score 0):

So I have sort of found a way to do so via python

```
cmds.optionMenu('filmbackMenu', edit = True, value = "<Name of the filmback>")
```

or

```
cmds.optionMenu('filmbackMenu', edit = True, select = "<Filmback index in the Film Gate drop-down list")
```

Do note that for the index method, the index starts from `1` instead from `0`

After that, run the following code so that it will reflect the changes onto the apertures and lens squeeze. Without doing so, it will only change the name of the filmback

```
mel.eval('AEwhichCameraFilmback <Name of Camera>.horizontalFilmAperture <Name of Camera>.verticalFilmAperture <Name of Camera>.lensSqueezeRatio;')
```

NOTE: I noticed that it works at times, it is not guaranteed. Still trying to find out why